# Angular 6 Lazy loading route

Tags: angular, routes

I wanted to add lazy loaded route for admin in my project. I'm using ASP Net Core backend and Angular 6 frontend, so my output dir for compile code is: wwwRoot/Angular/dist. When I compiled project, I see that file "admin-admin-module-ngfactory.js exists there, but when I try to enter page '/admin/dash', it throw error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk admin-admin-module-ngfactory failed.
(error: http://localhost:5000/admin-admin-module-ngfactory.js)
Error: Loading chunk admin-admin-module-ngfactory failed.
(error: http://localhost:5000/admin-admin-module-ngfactory.js)
```

Here is my routing modules:

admin-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: 'dash', component: AdminDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

and app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

UPDATE:

If I run project with dotnet run (with ng build --aot) it doesn't work, but if I launch only Angular app with ng serve --aot it works.

Comment: double check the path

Comment: I've checked path, I'm sure that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line in .angular-cli.json file.

```
"apps": [
{
  "deployUrl": "Angular-Build-Path/",
```

Thanks.

Comment: I added: "deployUrl": "/Angular/dist/", and it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: can you provide here the changes which you have made in your code, It will be easier for others to relate.

Answer (score 0):

According  deploy documentation of Angular:

> If you copy the files into a server sub-folder, append the build flag,
>   --base-href and set the  appropriately.

So, you should use the **--base-href** parameter in .angular-cli.json file.

Optionally, you can work in development mode without -base-href configuration(in the angular-cli- file) and only set it at aplication production build.

ng build --base-href=/Angular/dist/

References:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#simplest-deployment-possible

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag